# Configure default warn/error log with logback-classic/slf4j

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

I am trying to configure logback-classic to handle the following situation:
All messages originating from my.class with level debug or higher, should be sent to the stdout appender.

And all error messages of level warn or higher, should **also** go to the altout appender no matter where they originate. But I can't seem to get it to work.

I have tried this config, but the problem is that if I set additivity to true, then all messages logged to stdout are also sent to altout no matter their warning level. But if I set additivity=false then no messages originating from my.server are sent to altout even if they have a warn/error level.

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>Stdout: %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="ALTOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>Altout: %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name='my.class'  level='debug' additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="ALTOUT" />
  </logger>

  <root level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you are initializing the logger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration seems to be correct, except that you inverted STDOUT and ALTOUT (as per your initial description). Setting `additivity="true"` will log messages to both STDOUT and ALTOUT using the specified level.

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>Stdout: %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="ALTOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>Altout: %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="Flop"  level="error" additivity="true">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </logger>

  <root level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="ALTOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

With the following Java classes:

```
public class Flop {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Flop.class);


    public void plop() {
        log.debug("Flop debug");
        log.warn("Flop warn");
        log.error("Flop error");
    }
}

public class Main {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    public void prout() {
        log.debug("Main debug");
        log.warn("Main warn");
        log.error("Main error");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().prout();
        new Flop().plop();
    }
}
```

The result will be:

```
Altout: 14:55:26.288 [main] WARN  com.excilys.Main - Main warn
Altout: 14:55:26.292 [main] ERROR com.excilys.Main - Main error
Stdout: 14:55:26.292 [main] ERROR com.excilys.Flop - Flop error
Altout: 14:55:26.292 [main] ERROR com.excilys.Flop - Flop error
```

I.e. Main logs warn and above on STDOUT and Flop logs error and above on both STDOUT/ALTOUT. Setting `additivity="false"` will cause Flop to log only in STDOUT (but that's not what you want, as I understand from your question).

Answer (score 2):

Use the http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#thresholdFilter on the ALTOUT to filter all events below warning.